# WebApi and MVC 4: GetById and services in separate project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm working with webapi, MVC 4 project. (using repository pattern and Unit of Work)
I have two questions

1) The GetById of WebApi should return the entity or HttpResponseMessage?
If it's HttpResponseMessage, then Should it be...

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
{
    var car = Uow.Cars.GetById(id);
    return car == null ? Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, car) : Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound,);
}
```

or

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
{
    var car= Uow.Cars.GetById(id);
    if (car!= null) {
        return car;
    }
    throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
}
```

I'd like to follow RESTfull responses.

2) Is it logical to separate webapi services from the UI? I mean in one webapi project, the controllers with base ApiController and CRUD http opearations, so they can be called from anywhere/any devices directly, and then another webapi/MVC4 project which will call the services of the webapi project?

I'm asking this because having in the same controller the service and the handling that return a View for example sounds like coupling the service to the client which will be consuming it.

For example:
From this (in the same webapi controller):

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
{
    var car = Uow.Cars.GetById(id);
    return car!= null ? Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, car) : Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound,);
}

public ViewResult Details(long id)
{
    return View(Get(id));
}
```

Go to this:

```
public ViewResult Details(long id)
{
    return View(webapiService.Cars.Get(id));
}
```

Having the implementation of the Get in the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `HttpResponseMessage` or the entity `Car` as the return type. If you use `HttpResponseMessage` you would get more control on customizing some of the HTTP properties when you create the response.

When the action creates a resource then using the `HttpResponseMessage` as the return type provide you much flexible option to set the status code (201) and the location where the created resource can be accessed. See this [post](http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/3/creating_a_rest_service_using_asp_net_web_api) for more info.

REST not care about which way you use all it cares is when the caller asks for a resource the server should return the resource in a format that the caller can accept it with proper status code (200 if exists else 404).

You can move the WebAPI controllers into separate project if there is really a choice that the service could be consumed from different clients else avoid doing that. Once you move the WebAPI controllers into a separate project then you will face Cross-Domain issues when you try to consume it from the javascript in MVC project.

Answer (score 0):

Point 1:
It is logical to return the entity from actions in case of Web API but then we cannot control the HttpResponseMessage properties (like HttpStatusCode). Except that returning an entity is always a cleaner approach. We can control serialization, formatting etc in respective filters to get our job done. But you can never return car/HttpResponseMessage optionally as compiler will not let you compile a method with return type as HttpResponseMessage and return type Car.

Point 2:
Having separate controllers for view and rest calls is a good idea. I would suggest to have controllers with the same name but in different namespaces and then routes handle http calls separately (but prepending '/api/' to the rest calls. Having different actions in the same controller for ViewResult and HttpResponseMessage/Car is an option also but not as clean and separate.

Comment: Regarding Point1 answer. I know I can't return a Car if returning type is HttpResponseMessage. My question is what RESTfull things say about that. Does the caller party expects the entity or not?